nftables: oneliner to count, log (with limit) and drop
I am using nftables v0.9.6 and the geoip database to drop inbound traffic from specific countries. For example, I have in a chain:
meta mark 0x0000033a drop comment "block traffic from GB"

Now, I would like to count, log and drop the traffic. I think I should add these instructions (plus the definition of the named counter):
meta mark 0x0000033a counter name "drop_gb" log prefix "drop_gb:" drop comment "block traffic from GB"

Honestly I did not try it but I am confident it would work :-) Unfortunately I got stuck on the next step: I wanted to add a limit to the logging action to avoid disk getting filled up by logfiles (especially on small embedded platforms) in case of an prolonged attack.
I usually add a limit rate 120/minute burst 300 packets instruction before the log command as in:
meta mark 0x0000033a counter name "drop_gb" limit rate 120/minute burst 300 packets log prefix "drop_gb:" drop comment "block traffic from GB"

but I think here I would get the (unwanted) side effect that also the drop action will be "limited"!
I mean that with the above rule only the logged traffic will be dropped, getting the weird result that traffic over the threshold (a strong attack) won't be dropped. Am I right?
I'd like to keep the "oneliner" approach to have more readable rules (they are several and script-generated): is there any way to achieve "limited" log with "full" packet drop?
Thank you!
S.

Maybe a single long line is readable for people who have ultrawide 4K screens; personally I would say it's the opposite.
You're right that limit will take effect on all subsequent actions in that rule, not only on log. You'll need to split it into two rules like this:
meta mark 0x0000033a counter name "drop_gb" jump {
    limit rate 120/minute burst 300 packets log prefix "drop_gb:"
    drop comment "block traffic from GB"
}

This can be written as a single line using ; to separate the two inner rules.
nftables supports jump/goto to inline subchains in all recent kernel versions.
On a related note: I'd say those limits are still too high for logging – I'd rather bring them down as far as 1/minute, a lesson I have learned the hard way. (Turns out, letting iptables logs go to the console, and the console being ttyS0, can completely wedge the system when the IPMI Serial-over-LAN isn't fast enough – thus a rule that was meant to prevent an attack, did a better job at breaking things than the attack itself. I think this might have been fixed with the recent RT kernel printk changes, but you know... do you really need 120 identical messages about an attack?)

It would be a nice workaround but it seems my nft version (0.9.6, with kernel 4.19.0) is not keen to accept this syntax...

I overlooked that – this was actually added in nftables 0.9.7 and kernel 5.9. Both released ~4y ago.

Yep, this is the relevant commit.

The corresponding kernel commit might be: https://git.kernel.org/pub/scm/linux/kernel/git/torvalds/linux.git/commit/?id=d0e2c7de92c7f2b3d355ad76b0bb9fc43d1beb87 (part of the e80a07b^..e80a07b merge).
